# How to change the sound pitch on every oncollision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I get the sound effect like a piano when my object collide with other?

For play the sound on every collision I'm using now an      `audioData.PlayOneShot (hitSound);` where `hitSound` is a sound and `audioData` is an AudioSource. Is there any simple method to change the sound tone every time the object collide with other?

Comment: you can put your sounds in resources then load them and use them in your code

Answer (score 0):

The AudioSource object has a pitch property. Increasing its value on every hit up to a point and then reseting it may be a easy way to do it.

More info:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-pitch.html

Theres also a technique that allows the feeling of a endlessly increasing or decreasing tone, which involves the use of two waves of sound, in case it may be useful at some point.